# number of visualizations in RPubs (R community)

Tags: r

Is there a way to know how many views a post has on RPubs?
Since many year I had published a lot of rmardown documents using the RPubs platform freely available for RStudio users, but the problem is you don't have any idea of how many views does any especific post had.

Comment: Since RPubs is a private service run by RStudio this would probably be a better question for https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the how a private service works and it doesn't appear to involve any coding at all.